# Access VBA: Find item in combo box based on non-bound column

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a two-column combo box on an Access form representing a key-to-code mapping. The first column of the combo box is the 'bound column' (ie, the column used when `MyComboBox.Value` is called).

I need to dynamically set the `Value` of my combo box based on a value found in the second column. For eg, if my combo box source is:

```
Value | Code
===============
 A1    | ABCD
 A2    | EFGH
 A3    | IJKL
```

I can set the value of the combo box simply with `ComboBox.Value = "A2"`, but how would I do the same using the second column? `ComboBox.Value = "EFGH"` obviously isn't valid. Essentially looking for logic along the lines of `ComboBox.Value = ComboBox.ValueWhereSecondColumnEquals("EFGH")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And assuming it's not based on a table/query:

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To ComboBox.ListCount-1
    If ComboBox.Column(1, i) = "EFGH" Then
        ComboBox.Value = ComboBox.ItemData(i)
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: `to ListCount-1` :) I was just about to add this.

Comment: Sometimes the best answer is the simplest - can't believe just looping through it never crossed my mind!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your combo is based on a table, you can DLookUp the value in the table:

```
 ComboBox.Value = Dlookup("Value","Table","Code='" & sCode & "'")
```

Comment: This works too. It's not based on a table at the moment, but probably will be at some point

Comment: Kai, unless you have very few values, and by very few I mean 2 or 3, it should be based on a table for ease of maintenance and use in reporting and queries.

Comment: I know - the whole thing will later be back-ended to SQL Server but at the moment am waiting for a full mapping list to be provided and am just cobbling together a UI design (with zero back-end) to show the client for initial feeback.

Answer (score 0):

If the source is the value selected in a combobox, and the target is an unbound combobox set the .BoundColumn property of the target combobox to the appropriate column and then just assign the combobox values normally, as in cboX=cboY. Even if the target combobox is bound, you can dynamically change the bound column as needed.