# Access 2010 combo box -- can't DLookup the result after update

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a database where I am using a form as a front end to enter data into the table. I have a field `Manager Name` that is a combo box that pulls from a liked table. Here is my issue, I have another field  `Manager ID` that I am trying to auto-populate from the linked table based on the value selected for `Manager Name`, After Update on `Manager Name`. I tried to using the following code, but I don't get anything back:

`[Manager ID] = DLookup("[ID]", "tbl_PSRpt_import", "[Name]= forms![tbl_ManagerChange]![Manager Name]")`

`tbl_PSRpt_import` is the linked table.

There are other fields using this same setup (After Update of one field Dlookup the value to be put into another field) that work, but for some reason this does not. Could it be the fact that it is a linked table? Or something else?

Comment: It doesn't matter the table is linked.  Start again on the combo box.  Let the Access wizard build it for you.  Store the manager ID in the field, not the manager.  This is the usual way to handle this.

Comment: The combo box is a separate field from the `Manager ID`, which will be locked for user input. I need to store both pieces of information, as they are being fed to a excel spreadsheet to submit a request. I want to lookup the `Manager ID` based on what the user enters in `Manager Name` via the combo box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's name the control `cboManagerSelect`.  It's an unbound control, so there is nothing in the Control property.

The data for the combo box will be `ID, Name` -- two columns.

Under the Format tab of properties for that control, you can specify the column widths as `0",1.2"`.  This has the effect of hiding the first column.

Your VBA won't use a data look-up.  That's already done through this configuration.  Just use the `AfterUpdate()` event for that control:

```
MyForm!ManagerID = MyForm!cboManagerSelect.Column(0)
```

`Column(1)` would give you the name, but you want the ID so you take the first column `(0)`.

---

If you want to stay with `DLookup()`, then check this to see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15366878/122139.